# React - how to update a specific field in Object Array using useState in UseEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

At first, I create an object array `address` using `useState`.

In `useEffect`, I want to update `address` after I get the response from API.

The ultimate value of `address` should be

```
[
    { id: "unit", label: "Unit", value: "Unit 1" },
    { id: "floor", label: "Floor", value: "Floor 1" },
    { id: "block", label: "Block", value: "Block 1" }
]
```

How can I do it?

App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [address, setAddress] = useState([
    // the value will be updated in useEffect
    { id: "unit", label: "Unit", value: "" },  // Value should be Unit 1
    { id: "floor", label: "Floor", value: "" },// Value should be Floor 1
    { id: "block", label: "Block", value: "" } // Value should be Block 1
  ]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // let's pretent there is api GET request
    let responseData = {
      en: {
        unit: "Unit 1",
        floor: "Floor 1",
        Block: "Block 1"
      }
      // other language address which can be ignored
    };

    // How to update the update of address below??

  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

CodeSandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-microservice-qjuhh?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming all items in `address` have a matching value in `responseData` you could use:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // let's pretent there is api GET request
  let responseData = {
    en: {
      unit: "Unit 1",
      floor: "Floor 1",
      Block: "Block 1"
    }
    // other language address which can be ignored
  };
  
  setAddress((address) => (
    address.map((item) => ({ ...item, value: responseData.en[item.id] }))
  ));
}, []);
```

The code above loops through the `address` array and maps each item to one with an updated value found in `responseData.en`.

The reason I'm using a callback is because you should use a callback if the new state depends on the previous state. Since you only want to update a single property of an item (and not completely replace the state) the new state depends on the old state, thus you use a callback.

Comment: What happens if the language isn't `en`. This code won't work.

Comment: @Andy That is true, but the language is `en`. The comment clearly says *"other language address which can be ignored"*. So I assume OP want to specifically target the `en` language. For a variable language you can simply store the language in a variable/state and use `responseData[lang][item.id]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can update in the following way:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    // let's pretent there is api GET request
    let responseData = {
      en: {
        unit: "Unit 1",
        floor: "Floor 1",
        Block: "Block 1"
      }
      // other language address which can be ignored
    };

    // How to update the update of address below??
    setAddress((prevAddress) => [
      {
        ...prevAddress[0],
        value: responseData.en.unit
      },
      {
        ...prevAddress[0],
        value: responseData.en.floor
      },
      {
        ...prevAddress[0],
        value: responseData.en.Block
      }
    ]);
  }, []);
```

For your reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-silence-gs1yq?file=/src/App.js:425-1015

Comment: Any other dynamic way? If more fields(like buildings/Country) are required, I have to update more in order for it to work

Answer (score 0):

try like this, if en available, it will take en, else whatever first lang available

```html
      useEffect(() => {
        // let's pretent there is api GET request
        let responseData = {
          en: {
            unit: "Unit 1",
            floor: "Floor 1",
            Block: "Block 1"
          }
          // other language address which can be ignored
        };
        let languagePriority = null

        const availableLangs = Object.keys(responseData)
        if (responseData.en) {
         languagePriority = 'en'
        }
        if (!responseData.en && availableLangs.length) {
         languagePriority = availableLangs[0]
        }
        if (languagePriority) {
         const responseKeys = 
        Object.keys(responseData[languagePriority])
        const addressCopy = [...address]
        responseKeys.forEach(item => {
          addressCopy.find(addItem => {
          if (addItem.id === item) {
            addItem.value = response.en[item]
          }
          })
        })
        setAddress(addressCopy)
        }
        
        // How to update the update of address below??

      }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the object within `responseData` that separates it from the language.
2. [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the state array to create a new array of objects updated with the new value gained from `responseData`.

```js
const data = [{ id: "unit", label: "Unit", value: "" },{ id: "floor", label: "Floor", value: "" },{ id: "block", label: "Block", value: "" }];
const responseData = {en: {unit: "Unit 1",floor: "Floor 1",block: "Block 1"}};

const obj = Object.values(responseData)[0];

const result = data.map(({ id, value, ...rest }) => {
  return { id, value: obj[id], ...rest };
});

console.log(result);
```